# Unicode and the Google App engine SDK Log Console

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, logging, unicode

This has been driving me crazy, trying to figure out if my application has been handling Unicode correctly or not.
One of the main problems I'm experiencing is the Log Console doesn't appear to be correctly displaying unicode characters

```
    for index in range( len( input ) ):
        logging.info(  "ASCII   " + str( index )     +  ": " + str( input[ index ].encode( errors = 'backslashreplace' ) ) +  " -> " + str( ord( input[ index ] ) ) )
        logging.info( u"UNICODE " + unicode( index ) + u": " + unicode( input[ index ] )                                   + u" -> " + unicode( ord( input[ index ] ) ) )
```

With the above snippet, I get the following log output:

> INFO     2015-11-22 16:06:59,967 **init**.py:47] UNICODE 1251: M -> 77
>
> INFO     2015-11-22 16:06:59,967 **init**.py:46] ASCII   1252: \u0142 -> 322
>
> INFO     2015-11-22 16:06:59,967 **init**.py:47] UNICODE 1252: Å‚ -> 322
>
> INFO     2015-11-22 16:06:59,967 **init**.py:46] ASCII   1253: o -> 111
>
> INFO     2015-11-22 16:06:59,969 **init**.py:47] UNICODE 1253: o -> 111

As you can see, where it should print [ż](http://www.charbase.com/017c-unicode-latin-small-letter-z-with-dot-above) it actually prints [Å](http://www.charbase.com/00c5-unicode-latin-capital-letter-a-with-ring-above).
Is this some fundamental misunderstanding I have with how python handles unicode, or could it be a bug in the Google app engine sdk, or simply a misconfigured setting?

Comment: hopefully just some confusion, let's probe. what's `input` -- a string of bytes? or of unicode chars? If the latter what's `unicode(input[index])` if `input[index]` is already Unicode? And why do you think unichr(322) aka u`\u0142` should be a lowercase z with a dot (which I believe is unichr(380) aka u'\u017c') -- I think it's a lowercase l with a bar through it -- and apparently what's displayed is *two* characters, a \u00c5 followed by a tiny-comma mark that by copy and paste into a Python interpreter seems to be \u201a.

Comment: One of the problems is I'm not entirely sure. The snippet is part of a larger app that requests information about your upcoming events on facebook. I believe the data I'm given is utf-8 that's been encoded (decoded?) to fit into a json string.

You could use the following Polish word as an example:
"pożegnanie"
"po\u017cegananie"

Comment: If `input` is a byte string in utf-8, then walking it with a index growing each time by one makes no sense -- you get single *bytes* which outside of the full utf-8 content mean nothing. This needs a code example so I'll show it as an answer (code doesn't fit well in comments).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (according to further discussion in comments to the original Q) with taking a utf-8 string of bytes and walking it byte by byte -- a single non-ASCII byte from a utf-8 string, uprooted from the utf-8 context, makes no sense. To take an example offered in a comment by the OP (using Python 2.7 for congruence to what App Engine does use today):

```
2>>> s=u"pożegnanie"
2>>> s
u'po\u017cegnanie'
2>>> su=s.encode('utf8')
2>>> su
'po\xc5\xbcegnanie'
2>>> su.decode('latin-1')
u'po\xc5\xbcegnanie'
2>>> print su.decode('latin-1')
poÅ¼egnanie
```

The decode by latin-1 is just a trick I'm using to compactly say "interpret each byte on its own" (since latin-1 is a single-byte codec).

So this shows how an original `\u017c` (lowercase z with a dot on top) transmogrifies (via utf-8 then nonsensically interpreted byte by byte) into that "uppercase A with small circle on top" followed by something else (which in latin-1 happens to be the fraction "one-fourth").

To clarify exactly what `input` is, a `logging.info` of `type(input)` and `repr(input)` (or a relevant slice thereof, e.g `repr(input[1248:1258])` if the issues surface around index 1252) may likely help. I suspect the SDK is fine (but if it isn't, this will help diagnose what bug to open against it on the public App Engine Issue Tracker) and the problem is rather about unicode vs variously encoded and decoded byte strings.

Comment: This is what I got in my own case:
"""
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u01b0' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
"""
The related string is Vietnamese: "Mưa trên phố ngày xưa, lời yêu thương thì thầm trong mưa"